# CSS-Items get initialised again when hovering over them jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the page is loaded all boxes get initialised (when scrolling they slide in). Unfortunately when I hover one of these boxes (after they appeared) the get initialised again so they slide in again. What can I do in order to ignore the hovering? (I want to keep the :hoverShadow!)

Code:

```js
var allBoxes = $('.hoverShadow');

allBoxes.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible");
  }
});

currentWindow.scroll(function(event) {
  allBoxes.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hoverShadow {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: animateShadowOut;
}

.hoverShadow:hover {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: animateShadowIn;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 8px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.come-in
{
    transform: translateY(150px);
    animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}

.already-visible
{
    transform: translateY(0);
    animation: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="hoverShadow" id="middleBox">
  <h2 class="headline">Headline</h2>
  <div class="offerContent">
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `:hover` rule?

Comment: @Taplar Yes this works. But the hover-rule is necessary in this case. Is there any other solution?

Comment: What is `el.visible(true)`? It should be `el.is(":visible")`

Comment: animation-fill-mode: forwards;

Comment: You can also use `el.filter(":visible").addClass("already-visible");`

Comment: I'm not seeing any code that would cause anything to slide in...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for is the use of:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

It tells the browser to use the last keyframe of the animation as the new "permanent" styling for the element. This means the animation will not start over and the final location in the animation will stay the same.

Here is the documentation:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode